# Error in using Non Linear SVM in Scikit-Learn

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have a code to try to use Non Linear SVM (RBF kernel).

```
raw_data1 = open("/Users/prateek/Desktop/Programs/ML/Dataset.csv")
raw_data2 = open("/Users/prateek/Desktop/Programs/ML/Result.csv")

dataset1 = np.loadtxt(raw_data1,delimiter=",")
result1 = np.loadtxt(raw_data2,delimiter=",")

clf = svm.NuSVC(kernel='rbf')
clf.fit(dataset1,result1)
```

However, when I try to fit, I get the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/prateek/Desktop/Programs/ML/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 193, in fit
    fit(X, y, sample_weight, solver_type, kernel, random_seed=seed)
  File "/Users/prateek/Desktop/Programs/ML/lib/python2.7/site-packages/sklearn/svm/base.py", line 251, in _dense_fit
    max_iter=self.max_iter, random_seed=random_seed)
  File "sklearn/svm/libsvm.pyx", line 187, in sklearn.svm.libsvm.fit (sklearn/svm/libsvm.c:2098)
ValueError: specified nu is infeasible
```

[Link for Results.csv](http://1drv.ms/1VTOsJF)

[Link for dataset](http://1drv.ms/1Ku80Un)

What is the reason for such an error?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26987248/nu-is-infeasible

Comment: In the code you are using a `sigmoid` kernel but you say that you are using a `RBF` kernel. Which want do you actually want to use?

Comment: @BlackAdder Im sorry. I was even trying sigmoid kernel also. Ive corrected it.

Comment: @Evert so I must have values in (0,1) open interval and not [0,1] closed interval?

Comment: But in your code you are not specifying `nu` value, so the system is taking the default one: `0.5`.
Could you try different `nu` values in the range (0, 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `nu` parameter is, as pointed out in the documentation, "An upper bound on the fraction of training errors and a lower bound of the fraction of support vectors".

So, whenever you try to fit your data and this bound cannot be satisfied, optimization problem becomes infeasible. Therefore your error.

As a matter of fact, I looped from `1.` to `0.1` (decreasing in decimal units) and still got the error, then just tried with `0.01` and **no complaints arose**. But of course, you should check the results of fitting your model with that value, check if accuracy is acceptable on predictions.

> Update: actually I was curious and splitted your dataset to validate, output was **69%** accuracy (also I think your training set might be very little)

Just for reproducibility purposes, here, the quick test I performed:

```
from sklearn import svm
import numpy as np 
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

raw_data1 = open("Dataset.csv")
raw_data2 = open("Result.csv")
dataset1 = np.loadtxt(raw_data1,delimiter=",")
result1 = np.loadtxt(raw_data2,delimiter=",")

clf = svm.NuSVC(kernel='rbf',nu=0.01)
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(dataset1,result1, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)
clf.fit(X_train,y_train)
y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred, normalize=True, sample_weight=None)
```

Comment: the reason for such low accuracy are lot of factors. If u see the results.csv, most of them belong to group labeled 1. Also, there was nothing belonging to group 3. Also - yes- the training dataset is just 300+ points.